# Access control (IAM) on Azure Portal - Cannot see Resource group to which i have been granted access to

Tags: azureportal

I have granted access to a couple of users with different roles against resource group on Azure portal. User whom I have granted access rights do not see the resource group when they login to azure portal.

Have I missed something while granting access rights?

Comment: Did you follow this example ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure

Comment: Yes i did followed the article. After i added the user i can see them in the list although when user log in to their account they don't see resource to which i granted access.

Comment: Looks like its working with couple of clicks.
1. User with access right logs in to their azure account
2. On the top right corner click on "Account" and then select the invitee account details.
3. Once clicked through this then they are able to view Resource group.
Is this the way how it should work ?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably in the wrong Azure directory. You can solve this issue with the following steps.

1. Login to the azure portal here: https://portal.azure.com/ with your
   credentials
2. Click the top right icon which shows a generic person
   icon and opens a drop down about your profile/account
3. Click 'Switch Directory' and switch into the directory of the 
   organization where you have been granted access.
4. Look over to the left. You should now see the resources that you 
   were granted access to under 'All Resources'

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Portal just needed refreshing. Just switched the user directories and came back to the user directory I had given access to, then I could see the resource group under that user.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment than a separate answer. I know, "But I can't comment yet!" see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: this answer is usefull as comment in github

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to go to portal settings (gear icon in top bar), click on the default subscription filter and enable all subscriptions.